# How do I add an external library (Apache Commons Lang) to an Android Studio app manually?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I know how to work with Apache Commons Lang 3 library in an Android Studio app by implementing it in the build.gradle file using `implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'`. But I want to know if it's possible to include the Apache Commons Lang 3 library (or for that matter, any external library) in the Android app manually if I have the library downloaded on my PC? For example, like adding the .jar file of the library to Android Studio or something of that sort.

I'm asking from the viewpoint where I have a library folder in my PC which doesn't have an online link from which gradle can download and merge it with the Android Studio app automatically. How do I add that library to my Android app? Any elucidation on this matter is complimented.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options in the links listed below actually helped me to achieve my objective properly:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-import-external-jar-files-in-android-studio/
- https://medium.com/@jonathanmonga/how-to-add-libraries-in-android-studio-in-english-286db8b073c2

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps to add a local library as dependency (.jar):

- put the jar file into "libs" folder
- add the following line to your `build.gradle`, inside `dependencies`:

`compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

like:

```
dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I found two more methods.